# How to refer a certain place in a line in Python

Tags: python

I have this little piece of code:

```
g = open("spheretop1.stl", "r")
m = open("morelinestop1.gcode", "w")
searchlines = g.readlines()
file = ""
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if X1 in line and Y1 in line:
        m.write("start" + "\n")
```

with X1 = '206.9799' and Y1 = '0.1218346'

the line this file refers to looks like this:

```
  facet normal 4.650354e-002 -9.989174e-001 -1.217645e-003
      outer loop
         vertex 2.069799e+002 1.218346e-001 2.000000e+002
         vertex 2.069756e+002 1.218346e-001 1.997564e+002
         vertex 2.139428e+002 4.871899e-001 1.995131e+002
      endloop
   endfacet
```

I basically only want the file to write "start" + "\n" when the X1 and Y1 are in the same line AND are the first two variables in that line, as in the 3rd line above. So what I want to do is find X1 in the line at position x (17 spaces from left) and Y1 in the line at position y (31 spaces from left). Hope that its clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regular expressions.  [Live example](https://regex101.com/r/mS4rK9).

```
import re

X1 = 206.9799
Y1 = 0.1218346

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    r = re.match(r'^\s*vertex (\d+\.\d+e[-+]\d+) (\d+\.\d+e[-+]\d+) \d+\.\d+e[-+]\d+\s*$', line)
    if r and X1 == float(r.group(1)) and Y1 == float(r.group(2)):
        m.write("start" + "\n")
```

Be aware that comparing floats can be imprecise.  You have to decide how much imprecision you're willing to accept when comparing values.  You can use a function like this to compare two floats within a certain amount of precision.

```
def isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
     return abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)
```

Comment: The numbers X1 = 2.069799e+002 and Y1 = 1.218346e-001 are numbers from file x, and when these numbers are also encountered in the line from file y in that position, I want my script to write "start" + "\n".

Comment: Is it `X1 = 2.069799e+002`, or is it `X1 = '2.069799'` like you have in your question?  You also have no mention of file x in your question.

Comment: The number from file x is actually 206.9799, but I want to transform that to  2.069799e+002 (since it's the same), and thats how its noted in file y (stl file)

Comment: Put that information in your question and I'll update my answer.

Comment: file x would look like this:   G1 X251.76381 Y200.00000
G1 X200.00000 Y200.00000
G1 X200.00000 Y200.00000
G1 X200.00000 Y46.79111   etc

Comment: Yes, i prefer my X1 and Y1 as strings, so X1 would be '206.9799' and Y1 would be '0.1218346'. How would I have to adjust the code to run that?