# Print only a part of a whole line in Python

Tags: python, lines

My code so far looks like this:

```
g = open("spheretop1.stl", "r")
m = open("morelinestop1.gcode", "w")
searchlines = g.readlines()
file = ""

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "outer loop" in line:
        p4 = searchlines[i+1]
        p5 = searchlines[i+2]
        p6 = searchlines[i+3]
```

and the file spheretop1.stl looks like this:

```
solid spheretop1
   facet normal -4.647520e-002 -9.989174e-001 -2.029244e-003
      outer loop
         vertex 1.930371e+002 1.218346e-001 1.995131e+002
         vertex 1.930244e+002 1.218346e-001 1.997564e+002
         vertex 1.860572e+002 4.871899e-001 1.995131e+002
      endloop
   endfacet
   facet normal 4.650354e-002 -9.989174e-001 -1.217645e-003
      outer loop
         vertex 2.069799e+002 1.218346e-001 2.000000e+002
         vertex 2.069756e+002 1.218346e-001 1.997564e+002
         vertex 2.139428e+002 4.871899e-001 1.995131e+002
      endloop
   endfacet
   facet normal -2.323405e-002 -9.997293e-001 -1.217645e-003
      outer loop
         vertex 1.930244e+002 1.218346e-001 1.997564e+002
         vertex 1.930371e+002 1.218346e-001 1.995131e+002
         vertex 2.000000e+002 0.000000e+000 2.000000e+002
      endloop
   endfacet
```

What I want to do is have 'p4' be a group of numbers (floats) beginning with the first number in the vertex line, and following that the second number in the vertex line. So I want p4 to look like this:

`p4 = (193.0371, 0.1218346).`

After that I would like to have a p5 and a p6, p5 being `(193.0244, 0.1218346)` and p6 being `(186.0572, 0.4871899)`. Now what it gives me is the whole line under "outer loop", and I just want a specific part from the line. Anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refer a certain place in a line in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338441/how-to-refer-a-certain-place-in-a-line-in-python)

Comment: No, in this case I want to print a part of a line and not compare a part of line.

Comment: The only difference is your storing the parsed value rather than comparing it to something, you still get the value the exact same way.

Comment: @Henry: You may want to use a pre-made module for parsing STL files: https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl

Comment: Is the format of the file going to remain constant?

Comment: @sgrg yes the format is the same

Comment: Use `split` to get a list  `list1= ['vertex','x','y','z']` then pick the 2nd and 3rd element of that list and turn them into floats `p4=[float(list[1]),float(list[2])`.

Comment: @BrendanAbel How can i link my p4 p5 and p6 to those pieces of (parsed) line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As easy as this:

```
p4 = map(float, searchlines[i+1].split()[1:3])
```

Comment: Nice & elegant. Note, he doesn't want the z -value, so ` [1:3]`

Comment: Looks good! How do get the output as a tuple instead of a list though?

Comment: p4 = tuple(map(float, searchlines[i+1].split()[1:3]))

Answer (score 0):

```
list1= p4.split()   # gives  list1= ['vertex','x','y','z']
p4=[float(list[1]),float(list[2])]  # gives you a list of x and y
```